# Baby Rudin the connection between Theorem 2.36's Corollary and Theorem 2.38

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Theorem 2.36's corollary: If {$K_n$} is a sequence of nonempty compact sets such that $K_n \supset K_{n+1}$ (n = 1, 2, 3, ...), then $\cap_1^{\infty}K_n$ is nonempty.

> Theorem 2.38: If {$I_n$} is a sequence of intervals in $R^1$, such that $I_n \supset I_{n+1}$ (n = 1, 2, 3, ...), then $\cap_1^{\infty}I_n$ is nonempty.

Rudin meant it as closed intervals in theorem 2.38. My question is that he gave a proof for theorem 2.38, but doesn't it follow directly from theorem 2.36's Corollary?

Comment: It does follow from theorem 2.36

Comment: Why shouldnt a Theorem follow directly from a corollary?

Comment: Are you sure Rudin has proven that closed intervals are compact at this point in the book?

Comment: @JuliusL33t yeah I've just realized he hasn't proved that (the Heine-Borel Theorem) yet.

Comment: We don't know that closed intervals are compact.  Th. 2.38 is used to prove the Heine-Borel Th. 2.41 two pages later.